# How can I optimize this loop?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, optimization, loops

I've got a piece of code that returns a super-long string that represents "search results". Each result is represented by a double HTML break symbol. For example:

> Result1<br><br>Result 2<br><br>Result3

I've got the following loop that takes each result and puts it into an array, stripping out the break indicator, "`kBreakIndicator`" (<br><br>). The problem is that this lopp takes way too long to execute. With a few results it's fine, but once you hit a hundred results, it's about 20-30 seconds slower. It's unacceptable performance. What can I do to improve performance?

**Here's my code:**

*`content` is the original NSString.*

```
  NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  //Loop through the string of results and take each result and put it into an array
   while(![content isEqualToString:@""]){
   NSRange rangeOfResult = [content rangeOfString:kBreakIndicator];
   NSString *temp = (rangeOfResult.location != NSNotFound) ? [content substringToIndex:rangeOfResult.location] : nil; 
   if (temp) {
    [results addObject:temp];
    content = [[[content stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", temp, kBreakIndicator] withString:@""] mutableCopy] autorelease];
   }else{
    [results addObject:[content description]];
    content = [[@"" mutableCopy] autorelease];
   }
  }
//Do something with the results array.
[results release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is first use `NSString`'s `componentsSeparatedByString:` method that will give you an `NSArray`, like this:

EDIT: Assuming your `kBreakIndicator` constant is `<br>`:

```
NSArray *temp_results = [content componentsSeparatedByString:kBreakIndicator];
NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSString *result in temp_results) {
   if(result.length == 0) continue;
   [results addObject:result];
}
//do something with results...
[results release];
```

**Result of @invariant's answer**: http://cl.ly/3Z112M3z3K1V2t0A3N2L

**Result of my answer**: http://cl.ly/371b2j2H0Y1E110D2w0I

If your `kBreakIndicator` constant is `<br><br>`:

```
NSArray *result = [content componentsSeparatedByString:kBreakIndicator];
```

Comment: `results` starts off by having nothing in it. The loop will continue indefinitely because the length of `result` is always 0.

Comment: Ha! @JacobRelkin to the rescue - again. I need to test this before I accept it, naturally, but it sounds like what I was looking for.

We should get in touch. I am interested in learning more about that course you give. (My contact info is in my resume, which is on my website. MosheBerman.com)

Comment: @Aleksander I forgot to replace that to iterate through `temp_results`.

Comment: @Jacob I don`t see the need to introduce the filtering for empty strings. The original code dosn't do it, so `componentsSeparatedByString` alone should suffice.

Comment: @JacobRelkin - I don't seem to need the for loop, but the `componentsSeparatedByString:kBreakIndicator` code does the trick. My loop was an attempt at doing exactly that.

Comment: What's your test data Jacob? Works fine without empty strings for me. I'm guessing you have set the separator to `<br>` instead of  `<br><br>`

Comment: @invariant It's only natural that a constant named `kBreakIndicator` would be *one* `<br>` and not two, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Fair enough that you see it differently. To me though it's natural that since the data is separated by `<br><br>` the separator would be the same. And it needs less code.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
NSArray *results = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"<br><br>"];
```

Comment: `componentsSeparatedByString:` will return empty strings for this.

Comment: I've edited to clarify that the separator string is `<br><br>`, so no empty strings.